# Extracting Numbers From A String

Tags: c#, .net, string, split

I'm trying to manipulate a string..

For example:

```
string DiagnosesString  "250.00 03 350.0001 450.00 01 550.00 02";
```

Output

```
250.00
350.00
450.00
550.00
```

I tried to use a Split method. As you can see on my example in 350.0001 and its output is 350.00.

I can removed 03 , 02 , etc..

Question:
1.) How I will removed the o1 of 350.0001 get only 350.00?

here's my code:

```
string DiagnosisCodestemp = DiagnosesString.Replace(" 01 ", " ").Replace(" 02 ", " ").Replace(" 03 ", " ").Replace(" 04 ", " ").Replace(" 05 ", " ").Replace(" 06 ", " ").Replace(" 07 ", " ");
string[] DiagnosisCodesParts = DiagnosisCodestemp.Split();
```

Comment: You really need to be more specific regarding what the input might be, the example you are giving does not tell us much.

Comment: Could you provide more details on the format of the input string - is it always a 5 digit decimal (xxx.xx) followed by a 2 digit number (yy) for example?

Comment: Also, is "350.0001" correct? there is no space between the 350.00 and the 01 - that could make life hard!

Comment: Easy, 350.0001 - 0.0001 = 350.00 :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List list = new List();

```
       string DiagnosesString  =  "250.00 03 350.0001 450.00 01 550.00 02";

       string DiagnosisCodestemp = DiagnosesString.Replace(" 01 ", " ").Replace(" 02 ", " ").Replace(" 03 ", " ").Replace(" 04 ", " ").Replace(" 05 ", " ").Replace(" 06 ", " ").Replace(" 07 ", " ");

        string[] DiagnosisCodesParts = DiagnosisCodestemp.Split();

        foreach (var item in DiagnosisCodesParts)

        {

            string[] parts = item.Split('.');
            string num = parts[1];
            string finalValue = string.Empty;

            if (num.Length > 2)
            {
                num = num.Replace(num, "00");
                finalValue =  parts[0]+"."+num;
            }
            else
            {
                finalValue = parts[0] + "." + num;
            }

            list.Add(finalValue);
        }
```

o/p : 250.00    350.00    450.00    550.00

Comment: if you have another condition like if input string is 250.01 then you need to write another condition if you want o/p as 250.00

Comment: You are most welcome . And thanks for accepting my answer SilverFang

Comment: This will throw an exception if any of the items don't contain a .

Comment: If any item doesn't contain "." you mean ok then we can write condition  we can check if(item.contains(".") then it will go into loop or in else part we can write list.Add(item).

Answer (score 5):

```
var DiagnosisCodesParts =
    DiagnosesString.Split(' ')
                   .Where(s => !s.StartsWith("0"))
                   .Select(s => Decimal.Parse(s))
                   .Select(d => d.ToString("0.00");
```

Comment: @SilverFang: Then you should have specified that possibility in your question. Sorry, but we can't precisely solve your problem without a precise problem statement.

Comment: Maybe just a check for a decimal is ok with the input instead of a starts with?

Answer (score 3):

How about doing a Decimal.TryParse and format the decimal numbers.  THis will also weed out the bad values.

```
string DiagnosesString = "250.00 03 350.0001 450.00 01 550.00 02"; 
var diagnoses = DiagnosesString.Split(' ');
foreach(var diagnosis in diagnoses)
{
  decimal temp;
  if(diagnosis.Contains(".") && Decimal.TryParse(diagnosis, out temp))
  {
    // do something
    var value = temp.ToString("0.00");
  }
}
```

Comment: How will it remove the bad entries; `03` will parse correctly by `Decimal.Parse`?

Comment: just a note: you can use `Split(' ')` or `Split(' ', ';', ':')` - don't need to create new array.

Answer (score 2):

If you are dealing with numeric values, I would recommend parsing them into actual numeric types, e.g. using `Decimal.Parse` or `Decimal.TryParse`.  You can then use formatting to convert it back to a string, e.g. `myNumber.ToString("N2")`

Answer (score 2):

You can parse them as a double. I like to use `XmlConvert` for this:

```
foreach (var s in diagnosisCodesParts)
{
    var d = XmlConvert.ToDouble(s);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format({0:2}, d));
}
```

Comment: Because XML defines how to serialize doubles. I get headaches, whenever I try to parse a double, since you need to set the NumberFormatProvider properly, otherwise bad things might happen. See that period in the input? Is that a thousands separator or a decimal point? But yes, you could also just specify the correct formatting options for `double.Parse`.

Comment: Interesting, didn't know that. +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Try aplitting on the space.

```
string DiagnosisCodestemp = DiagnosesString.Replace(" 01 ", " ").Replace(" 02 ", " ").Replace(" 03 ", " ").Replace(" 04 ", " ").Replace(" 05 ", " ").Replace(" 06 ", " ").Replace(" 07 ", " "); 
string[] DiagnosisCodesParts = DiagnosisCodestemp.Split(' ');
```

This should produce an array with values and you can filter for the ones you need.  You can then convert the values to decimal and round to 2 places to remove the extra values.

Answer (score 1):

you could match the numbers using a regex

```
/\d+\.\d+/
```

but it depends whether you can define your number more precisely or not.

```
decimal number;
string DiagnosesString = "250.00 03 350.0001 450.00 01 550.00 02";

foreach(var num in Regex.Matches(DiagnosesString, @"\d+\.\d+"))
{
    Decimal.TryParse(num.ToString(), out number);
    Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("0.00"));
}
```

probably you even need a regex like this:

```
/(\d+.\d\d)\d*/
```

to match only numbers in the format 0.00... you should provide more data how you want your data to be parsed..

Answer (score 1):

1) convert the string to a decimal
2) round the decimal to 2 decimal places
3) convert it back to a string

Answer (score 1):

string DiagnosesString  =  "250.00 03 350.0001 450.00 01 550.00 02";

string DiagnosisCodestemp = DiagnosesString.Replace(" 01 ", " ").Replace(" 02 ", " ").Replace(" 03 ", " ").Replace(" 04 ", " ").Replace(" 05 ", " ").Replace(" 06 ", " ").Replace(" 07 ", " ");

```
        string[] DiagnosisCodesParts = DiagnosisCodestemp.Split();

        foreach (var item in DiagnosisCodesParts)

        {

            string[] parts = item.Split('.');
            string num = parts[1];
            if (num.Length > 2)
            {
                num = num.Replace(num, "00");
            }

        }
```

Comment: and if input have number 250.01?  your code gives result 250.00 am I right?

Comment: I din't check for tht condition it still give 01 not 00 if input code is 250.01

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm not sure I completely understood your question, but I'll try.

1. You split as you've done before.
2. You filter/ignore all strings with a length of 2 or less.
3. You convert the strings left in your array to double.
4. You round those values to 2 numbers after the point.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to convert the string to a numerical value, I choose decimal as it does not lose precision like double or float. Then you can use the format string specifier to convert it to the decimal form you want:

```
var list = List<string>();
foreach(var s in splitString) {

  // code to rule out 02, 01, etc. goes here

  decimal tmp;
  if (decimal.TryParse(s, out tmp)) {
     var code = tmp.ToString("0.00");
     list.Add(code);
  } else {
     // something went wrong, handle it here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string input = "250.00 03 350.0001 450.00 01 550.00 02";
        Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"[0-9]+[/.][0-9]+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        while (match.Success) 
        {
            string key = match.Value;
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:0.00}", Convert.ToDecimal(key, new CultureInfo("en-US"))));
            match = match.NextMatch();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a little off with match value.

Comment: Was more than a little off, sorry for the mess... been cleaned up and tested.